# Why doesn't sed's automatic printing deliver the expected results?

Tags: sed

#### What Works

This sed script works as intended:

```
$ echo -e "2\n1\n4\n3" | sed -n 'h; n; G; p'
1
2
3
4
```

It takes pair of input lines at a time, and swaps the lines. So far, so good.

#### What Doesn't Work

What I *don't* understand is why I can't use sed's automatic printing. Since sed automatically prints the pattern space at the end of each execution cycle (except when it's suppressed), why is this not equivalent?

```
$ echo -e "2\n1\n4\n3" | sed 'h; n; G'
2
1
2
4
3
4
```

What I *think* the code says is:

1. The input line is copied to the hold space.
2. The next line is read into the pattern space.
3. The hold space is appended to the pattern space.
4. **The pattern space (line1 + newline + line2) is printed automatically** because we've reached the end of the execution cycle.

Obviously, I'm wrong...but I don't understand why. Can anyone explain why this second example breaks, and why print suppression is needed to yield the correct results?

Comment: To work it without `-n` use `sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `n` command causes sed to print the current buffer before it reads the next line.  Here's the description from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html

```
[2addr]n
    Write the pattern space to standard output if the default
    output has not been suppressed, and replace the pattern
    space with the next line of input, less its terminating <newline>.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "2\n1\n4\n3" | sed 'h;N;s/.*\n//;G'
1
2
3
4
```

or this (GNU sed):

```
echo -e "2\n1\n4\n3" | sed '1~2{h;d};2~2G'
1
2
3
4
```

To find out what will be printed use `l` or if you're using GNU `l0`